# What is the best of two approaches to achieve DB Replication?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-replication

we have two approaches to achieve DB Replication:

1. Master-Master replication.
2. Master, 1 Primary Slave, 1 Secondary slave.

I am planning to analyze these two approaches and prepare a comparison report with a recommendation.Currently, I have setup the replication environment using Master-Master replication.

Please provide me some pointers with details analysis.

Comment: You might target www.serverfault.com for this. You stand a greater chance of getting this particular question answered there, IMO.

Comment: Is this a question anyways? I would like to see how much locking affects the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a long, canonical answer to general replication questions at [Postgresql replication in rails with data-fabric gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566376/postgresql-replication-in-rails-with-data-fabric-gem/15628761#15628761)

This being said the general advice is worth noting here again.  Master-master replication is incredibly complex and requires that you think through conflict resolution to a very high level of detail.  It may require programming to do that.

If at all possible go with master-slave.  Many solutions may "just work" here.  Master-master can never be guaranteed to "just work."  It requires a lot of additional complexity to make it work the way you want it to.